# Short Length Authentication Token

Tags: java, jwt

I want to encode the userdetails to a token and at the server side i need to decode the details. I used JWT token concept.It works perfect. But the problem is that I need token having length less than 10 characters according to the business requirement.JWT token is always a large length token. Is there any technique to limit the length of JWT. Or is there any other library available for short length token encoding?. Please anyone help me out of this

Answer (score 4):

It all depends on what you consider to be the "userdetails" [sic]™.

If "userdetails" are, say, a `long` `id`, then you should be able to fit it within the JWT, together with other information that the JWT has to contain.

But if "userdetails" are user name, home address, city, zipcode, billing address, favorite color, pet name, and the kitchen sink, then of course, there is no way you are ever going to fit that in 10 characters, no matter what compression algorithm you use.

So, it is not a matter of finding some library that can accomplish this, there is no such library, and there can be no such library, because information theory says that it cannot be done.

Be advised that a 10 character limit for the JWT is a very restricting limit.  On the other hand, it is not a good idea to store too much information in the JWT.  Generally, some kind of number that can be used to identify the user should be enough.

Comment: Even with a short id will not be possible

Answer (score 4):

A 10-character JWT is simply not possible

```
hhhhhh.ppppp.sssss
```

Two of them will be dots `.`. The content is base64 url encoded, which adds an extra size of 33%. We have now six (6) characters, but if you still believe you can include your data here, think that the signature using HMACSHA1 will produce 20 bytes ( ~27 characters in b64u)

You would need and opaque random token with a corresponding session managed in server, or increase the limit

Answer (score 2):

JWT has 3 parts,

1. The header - which has info of which algos are used for signing and encoding
2. the body - which is a base64 encoding of data you want to send
3. The signature- which is HS256 hash(default) to ensure no tampering has been done.

Now if you need a smaller token you can write your own impl for tokens. With a custom impl you can straight away skip the head as you can have some default hashing algo for your project. Second in the body you can just send the id and have all info being later derived from it. For the third part Hashing in theory atleast can give you a fixed length hash for any length string, so if you find a hashing module with sufficient github stars that lets you set the hash size you're golden.